# How to force HSTS in Nexus 3

Tags: jetty-9, nexus3

HSTS is not showing up as enabled in Nessus Scans on the port serving Nexus 3.16.1-02

Hello,

First time posting -

I'm trying to get HSTS enabled on `Nexus OSS 3.16.1-02`

From what I've read, this is enabled by default in the `jetty-https.xml` file for the application.

I've created an edited `jetty-ssl.xml` and added it to the `/etc/jetty/` directory and the `nexus.properties` `args` for which xml files to call.

After rebooting the application and looking at the logs, everything looks good. The application is available, but Nessus scans for the HSTS vulnerability are still coming back positive.

The default https://localhost:443/nexus is currently configured behind an F5 reverse-proxy and HSTS is enabled on the F5, ssl is enabled in the application as well, terminating on port 443.

`nexus.properties` is calling for the `jetty.xml`,`jetty-https.xml`,`jetty-ssl.xml`,`jetty-requestlog.xml` when the application starts.

Any additional information on why this might coming up still would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

MCarrica

This is the nexus.properties

```
application-port-ssl=443
nexus-args=${jetty.etc}/jetty.xml,${jetty.etc}/jetty-ssl.xml,${jetty.etc}/jetty-https.xml,${jetty.etc}/jetty-requestlog.xml
nexus-context-path=/nexus
```

This is from the jetty-https.xml for the HSTS enabled

```
Arg><New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SecureRequestCustomizer"/></Arg>
```

Nessus scans are still showing HSTS is not enabled on port 443 on the server that is serving the application

Comment: I've finally managed to resolve this.

Comment: I came across a lot of documentation on this, an over abundance, but no real direct documentation from Sonatype other than this is "enabled by default" in the application. I had to create a jetty-rewrite.xml to finally get this to work. The app now only calls the jetty.xml, jetty-https.xml, jetty-requestlog.xml and the jetty-rewrite.xml that I added in. I'll post the contents of the rewrite for anyone else not familiar entirely familiar with this.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the contents of the **rewrite.xml**

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- configure rewrite handler                                   --> 
    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <Get id="oldhandler" name="handler"/>

    <Set name="handler">
     <New id="Rewrite" class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler">
      <Set name="handler"><Ref id="oldhandler"/></Set>
      <Set name="rewriteRequestURI">true</Set>
      <Set name="rewritePathInfo">true</Set>
      <Set name="originalPathAttribute">requestedPath</Set>

<Call name="addRule">
        <Arg>
          <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.HeaderPatternRule">
            <Set name="pattern">/*</Set>
            <Set name="name">Strict-Transport-Security</Set>
            <Set name="value">max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains</Set>
          </New>
        </Arg>
      </Call>
     </New>
    </Set>

</Configure>
```